# R - plot the values of a matrix

Tags: r, plot, error-handling

I have an `32x32` matrix called I and would like to try to plot it. I.e. the two axes should range from 1 to 32 each and on the `z-axis` I would like to see the different values.
If it is possible to connect those points even better, not the most important part right now.

I've tried it using the package "`library(emdbook)`", however the following line

```
curve3d(I[x,y], xlim=c(1:N), ylim=c(1:N))
```

However, it delivers me the error `"Error in I[x, y] : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable".`

I'm happy for any suggestion on what to change :)

Thank you!

Comment: Please provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) when you're seeking for assistance.

Comment: how about a heat map? I'm thinking that if you want a 3D, then you must have a sort of matrix data for each axis?

Answer (score 1):

You can produce a surface plot e.g. by using `persp`:

```
## Example data:
x <- (1:32)/32
y <- (1:32)/32
model <- function (a, b){
    1 - (a-0.5)^2 - (b-0.5)^2
} 
z <- outer(x, y, model)

## Simple surface plot:
persp(x,y,z,box = TRUE, theta = -40, phi = 20)
```

[image: simple surface plot]

But as @din stated, a heatmap might be more suitable:

```
## Simple heatmap:
image(t(z))
```

[image: simple heatmap]